# Stop scroll bouncing in browser

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using the IE10 browser on Windows 8 touch screen device to test my web page. The front end of my web page is build on JSP and JavaScript.

I my issue that, when a user touches their browser, drags their finger downwards, and the browser shows a blank spot above the web page I had loaded?

Is there way to disable this in browser, or any JavaScript by which I can handle this?

Comment: This sounds like browser-native functionality, not anything DOM-controllable.  Is there a specific reason you want to disable this?

Comment: Thanks David. As i said, i m using the touch device for testing my web application. My testing team has open a defect for this. As when  scroll bar appears and we pull the screen up or down using finger they see lots of space up or bottom of the browser.

Comment: not sure if we have any browser setting to disable the vertically bounce